# Facebook/php-webdriver with Selenium/Firefox/Gecko: WebDriverCurlException/EOF reading marionette message

Tags: firefox, selenium

I want to use `facebook/php-webdriver`, with Firefox.
I have the Selenium 3.4 jar, Firefox 52.1 and Geckodriver 16.1 (made it executable and added the folder to PATH).

I installed Firefox with also Xvfb, because of I have read that was needed, with these commands:

```
sudo yum install firefox Xvfb libXfont Xorg
Xvfb :99 -ac -screen 0 1280x1024x24 &
export DISPLAY=:99
```

I runned Selenium with the Geckodriver provided, with these commands:

```
java -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver="/opt/bin/geckodriver" -jar  selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar
```

This is the code in my php file:

```
namespace Facebook\WebDriver;

include("vendor/autoload.php");

use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\DesiredCapabilities;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver;

$host = "http://localhost:4444/wd/hub";
$profile = new Firefox\FirefoxProfile();
$capabilities = DesiredCapabilities::firefox();
$capabilities->setCapability(Firefox\FirefoxDriver::PROFILE, $profile);
$capabilities->setCapability('marionette', true);
$driver = RemoteWebDriver::create($host, $capabilities);

$driver->get("http://www.google.nl");
$driver->manage()->timeouts()->implicitlyWait = 10;
```

Selenium runs, but I see these errors in the terminal `connection refused` and `Assertion failure .. Should successfully create image decoding`.

In the browser I see this error message:

```
Uncaught exception 'Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\WebDriverCurlException' with message 'Curl error thrown for http POST to /session
```

If I try another url, I get `EOF reading marionette message`.

What do I have to do to make Selenium work correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot use firefox with seleium, too. My error message is different. But maybe the problem is the same.

After I installed java, it opens the page automatically:
https://java.com/zh_TW/download/installed8.jsp

Firefix says that they have limits for plugins since firefox version 52, published on 2017 March. Chrome says it does not support NPAPI, so it wont execute all java.

Maybe this is what caused the problem?

Firefox error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\UnknownServerException' with message 'The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.gecko.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver. The latest version can be downloaded from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases' in D:\wwwroot\example\httpdocs\vendor\facebook\webdriver\lib\Exception\WebDriverException.php:114 Stack trace: #0 D:\wwwroot\example\httpdocs\vendor\facebook\webdriver\lib\Remote\HttpCommandExecutor.php(320): Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\WebDriverException::throwException(13, 'The path to the...', Array) #1 D:\wwwroot\example\httpdocs\vendor\facebook\webdriver\lib\Remote\RemoteWebDriver.php(126): Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\HttpCommandExecutor->execute(Object(Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\WebDriverCommand)) #2 D:\wwwroot\example\httpdocs\test.php(19): Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver::create('http://local in D:\wwwroot\example\httpdocs\vendor\facebook\webdriver\lib\Exception\WebDriverException.php on line 114
```

Chrome error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\UnknownServerException' with message 'The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.gecko.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver. The latest version can be downloaded from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases' in D:\wwwroot\example\httpdocs\vendor\facebook\webdriver\lib\Exception\WebDriverException.php:114 Stack trace: #0 D:\wwwroot\example\httpdocs\vendor\facebook\webdriver\lib\Remote\HttpCommandExecutor.php(320): Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\WebDriverException::throwException(13, 'The path to the...', Array) #1 D:\wwwroot\example\httpdocs\vendor\facebook\webdriver\lib\Remote\RemoteWebDriver.php(126): Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\HttpCommandExecutor->execute(Object(Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\WebDriverCommand)) #2 D:\wwwroot\example\httpdocs\test.php(19): Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver::create('http://local in D:\wwwroot\example\httpdocs\vendor\facebook\webdriver\lib\Exception\WebDriverException.php on line 114
```